# Dynamically changing class at Fixed navbar on scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm using bootstap for this one.

I want the class of each  will change when scrolling to its section.

I successfully did that when I want to add 'active' or remove it.

but I bought an html design using 'selected',

to make it clear this is a sample of what I want to do [(--HERE--)](http://jsfiddle.net/anjzb/)

this one only changes 'active' and each one is a 'link',

but in my work its 'selected' and each one is a 'scroll-link',

these are my buttons that I want to change:

```
<li class="home">
<a href="#home" class="scroll-link selected" data-id="home">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#about" class="scroll-link" data-id="about">About</a>
</li>
```

and this is a section example :

```
<section id="home" class="slider-bg">
```

and this is the java script that I did:

```
<script class="scroll-link">
            // ADDS ACTIVE CLASS TO LINKS WHEN SECTION WITH THE SAME SELECTOR AS THE HREF IS REACHED (CLASS .LINK IS NEEDED ON ALL <a> TAGS)

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(window).scroll(function () {

                    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

                    $('.scroll-link').each(function (event) {
                        if (y >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 40) {
                            $('.scroll-link').not(this).removeClass('selected');
                            $(this).addClass('selected');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

            // SMOOTH SCROLLING (with negative scroll of 40 for header)

            $(function () {
                $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
                    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                        var target = $(this.hash);
                        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                        if (target.length) {
                            $('html,body').animate({
                                scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 40)
                            }, 850);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            vent.preventDefault();
                </script>
```

and this is all the includes that the designer did:

```
<!-- jQuery & Helper library --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.appear.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-latest.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/retina.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack8cbb.js?v=2.1.5"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/stellar.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gmap.min.js"></script>
```

As you see I did write in my script:

```
vent.preventDefault();
```

this line will Override what ever preventing this from happening.

Please help me I'm new to web pages, But I'm a fresh graduate from CS.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem of `vent.preventDefault();`, this should be like `event.preventDefault();` and inside the function where you pass `event` as a parameter, like:

```
<script class="scroll-link">
            // ADDS ACTIVE CLASS TO LINKS WHEN SECTION WITH THE SAME SELECTOR AS THE HREF IS REACHED (CLASS .LINK IS NEEDED ON ALL <a> TAGS)

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(window).scroll(function () {

                    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

                    $('.scroll-link').each(function (event) {
                        if (y >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 40) {
                            $('.scroll-link').not(this).removeClass('selected');
                            $(this).addClass('selected');
                        }
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                });
            });

            // SMOOTH SCROLLING (with negative scroll of 40 for header)

            $(function () {
                $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
                    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                        var target = $(this.hash);
                        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                        if (target.length) {
                            $('html,body').animate({
                                scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 40)
                            }, 850);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

                </script>
```

at the end of script it didn't get any `event` data.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Arjun for the answer, I did what you said and still it didn't work. =(

Comment: I did it locally like this one and its working perfectly!, but in my home page its just not working I don't know why =(.

Comment: There are no errors! I even tried to remove the includes one by one, it just stopped on bootstrap, which it can't work with out it any way.

Comment: i tried this with bootstrap it works fine with that!

Comment: could a CSS file override my function by any way ?

Comment: yes that can be possible. you can give !important to css properties.

Comment: When I tried it I found this error, which wasn't appearing last time! this is it : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined " and its on the line of my script !

Comment: its a JavaScript error, Many thanks Mr.Arjun for all the help, I appreciate it.